# SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) Windows Service greyed out

Tags: installation, windows-services, sql-server-express

I Installed SQL Server Express on my work PC, and had it up and running at the time of installation.
But I guess after a restart of PC, the Windows Service "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" can no longer be started.

I have my normal user, and an Admin-User for my PC.
When I open services.msc with my normal user I see the service, but all functionality is greyed out.
When I open services.msc with my admin user, the service is not there.

In my years of working with windows services, I've never experienced a "missing" service from services.msc before.

I've looked in registry here: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services
With both my normal and admin user I see these services:
SQLAgent$SQLEXPRESS
SQLBrowser
SQLTELEMETRY$SQLEXPRESS

But not this: "MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS"

Installation:
I don't remember in detail, but I'm pretty sure I just double clicked the installation launcher, and gave my admin-user when prompted for admin permissions.

Do you have any idea what is going on ?